# How to extract the leaf/branch values of a python n-nested dict efficiently?

Tags: python, dictionary

I have an n-layered dict of dicts and want to get the leaf values by a certain series of keys.

So:

```
example_dict = {'level_one':
    {'level_two_a':
        {'level_three_a':[1,2,3], 
         'level_three_b':[4,5,6]
        }, 
     'level_two_b':
        {'level_three_c':[7,8,9], 
         'level_three_d':[10,11,12]
        }
    }
}
```

Sometimes I will want to query:

```
example_dict['level_one']['level_two_a']['level_three_a']
```

other times I need:

```
example_dict['level_one']['level_two_b']
```

The real nested dict is very large, so I want to avoid something like:

```
result_dict = copy.deepcopy(example_dict)
search_key = ['level_one', 'level_two_a']
for term in search_key:
 result_dict = copy.deepcopy(result_dict[term])
```

Is there a more memory efficient method?

Comment: Why would you need to copy anything? Are you altering the dictionaries at all? Your copies get replaced by deeper copies in any case, so that's a waste of your processor time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, don't create so many copies. Just reference the subdict:

```
result = example_dict
search_key = ['level_one', 'level_two_a']
for term in search_key:
    result = result[term]
```

As long as you are not altering the `result` dict, making a copy is pointless. Since you discard the previous copy and make a new one on every iteration, you are wasting CPU time as well as memory.

Even if you did have to modify `result` and don't want those changes to affect `example_dict`, you only need to copy the final `result` value after looping.